# HTTPClient PostAsync() with async and await never returns message

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

My problem is when I try to call my Web API rest Service from an mvc application using HttpClient PostAsync(), my web api never return the response message.

Here is the mvc app code:

```
public async Task<string> sendToWebAPI(string _obj)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebAPIRestService"]);
            StringContent _jsonParameter = new StringContent(_obj, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.PostAsync("api/webAPIController/", _obj).ConfigureAwait(false);               
            var WebAPIResponse = await Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return WebAPIResponse;

        }
    }
```

MVC Web API Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> Dowork([FromBody] string _obj)
    {
      HttpResponseMessage result = Request.CreateResponse(_obj != "" ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
      return result;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please use camelCase for naming your variables and PascalCase for naming your methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your API code is currently not returning a string. It is returing either OK or InternalServerError. Modify your code as follows.

```
bool isOK = string.isNullOrEmpty(_obj);
result = isOK ? request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, _obj) :
request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Invalid Data");
```